# How to get Unique ID of Outlook 2003 in VSTO addin

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, outlook-2003

I am developing an Outlook 2003 addin using VSTO in VisualStuido2008.  My requirement is that, when user select a calendar meeting and click on addin, it should be pushed to out application which manage BU interactions.  However, if any other person, who got the meeting invitation try to push same meeting again from other outlook instance, then there should be a machanism to Identify that it has already been pushed and can not be re-pushed.  Can we get Unique ID from MeetingObject which in unique at exchange server level.

Comment: As per my knowledge EntryID is not unique across the Outlook Server.  When u move meeting from one folder to another, value of EntryID changes.

Comment: You are correct: "Solutions should not depend on the EntryID property to be unique unless items will not be moved."

Comment: So EntryID will different for same meeting on different machines. I want a mechanism to identify that meeting on different machines are same meeting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in below article.  If perfectly works for me.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/899919